# error while installing some python modules/ error related to visual studios/ error while installing pycrypto, I had tried many ways but still unlucky

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pip, pycrypto

```
 winrand.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ','
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycrypto

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip+pycrypto

Comment: PyCrypto is dead. See https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/238 Use [PyCryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/).